# QgsVectorLayerCache causes QGIS to crash when called within def run(self)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt, qgsvectorlayer

This is in reference to the [similar question regarding QgsVectorLayerCache](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201544/qgis-qgsattributetablemodel-only-loads-when-called-without-a-function-in-python) .
The original code is taken from [here](https://webgeodatavore.github.io/pyqgis-samples/gui-group/QgsFeatureListView.html)

I'm trying to implement this method within the def run(self) method.

```
 def run(self):

    new_dialog = QDialog()

    new_dialog.resize(270, 210)

    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    feature_list_view = QgsFeatureListView(new_dialog)

    vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 1000)

    # for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    #     if layer.name() == 'Pins':
    #         # pins_layer = layer
    #         self.pinLayer = layer
    #         self.provider = self.pinLayer.dataProvider()

    attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)

    attribute_table_model.loadLayer()
    attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(
        canvas,
        attribute_table_model
    )
    feature_list_model = QgsFeatureListModel(attribute_table_filter_model)
    feature_list_model.setDisplayExpression('"Pins"')
    feature_list_view_delegate = QgsFeatureListViewDelegate(feature_list_model)
    feature_list_view.setModel(feature_list_model)
    # feature_list_view.setItemDelegate(feature_list_view_delegate) # Crash if uncommented. TODO: fix issue

    new_dialog.show()
```

Debugging it with PyCharm has revealed that this line here causes QGIS to crash:

```
vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 1000)
```

How can I put this in a proper function without causing a crash?
QgsVectorLayerCache should still be availabe in QGIS 2.18 according to the  [API docu](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayerCache.html)

Comment: Possible the same fix as https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/308933/28443